# How to display too many columns in angular ui grid

Tags: angularjs

In the angular ui grid i have too many columns to display.

Want to display extra columns as expand collapse under each row.

Which means expand/collapse button will be provided for each row and while exanding a particular row the extra columns headertemplate will b displayed along wil b displayed along with column values.

Is it poasible with angular ui grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as , there is no an option for that.

You can use the following to make things work as you wish:

remove default row headers by setting to false enableExpandableRowHeader

adding a custom row header by calling $scope.gridApi.core.addRowHeaderColumn

For reference :

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/114_row_header.

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/216_expandable_grid.

Comment: Thank you for quick response